# Laravel Getting User From Post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationships

I have 3 tables that are related to each other.

Users, Clients, Notes

Users can add notes to a client.

The notes table has the following

```
id, user_id, client_id, note
```

On my clients page "client/{id}" I am printing all the notes that have been added for the particular client.

However, I am unable to get the name of the user from the Users table from the note.

It says Trying to get property of non-object when i try to pull the name of the User who posted the note.

ClientController

```
$client = Client::find($cid);

    if (empty($client)) {
        return Redirect::to('contact');       //redirect to contacts if contact not found
    } else {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('clients.show')->with('client', $client);
    }
```

Client view

```
@foreach ($client->notes as $note)
    {{ $note->note }} //This works just fine.
    Posted by: {{ $note->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

My Note model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
}
```

My User model:

```
public function notes() {
    return $this->hasMany('Note','user_id');
}
```

If I try and use the function I can do something like

```
$note->user()->get()
```

But this will print out the entire array (it is the correct array) of the user row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
**Change this line**

```
$client = Client::find($cid);
```

**To**

```
$client = Client::find($cid)->load('notes.user');
```

**Or**

```
$client = Client::find($cid)->with('notes.user')->get();
```

Comment: @NyseX. Test again `with` solution. I think it'll  properly work

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `belongsTo` and `hasMany` need the full path to the model they refer to.

So:

**Notes**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Users**

```
public function notes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Note');
}
```

Comment: That's doesn't work. Forgot to mention also its Laravel 4.2

Comment: Woah that's a quick downvote. Googling this seems that a lot of people have this error, so I just thought I'd drop it here. Also I wasn't aware that this was still Laravel 4.2, which means there's things I'm thinking of in Laravel 5 that just don't work for OP.

Comment: I hate downvotes without explanations -.-' Thanks anyway and I hope you'll find the answer!

Comment: @NyseX Why would you upvote an answer that you know doesn't work?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Why would anyone downvote an answer thats seems legitimate without telling why?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for the problem by using

```
$note->user()->pluck('name')
```

Don't think this is the best way. Though, it works.